# IntelliJ IDEA doesn't start: Cannot load a JDK class: com.sun.jdi.Field

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

When I try to start IntelliJ I get a popup saying

```
Cannot load a JDK class: com.sun.jdi.Field 
Please ensure you run the IDE on JDK rather than JRE.
```

It's really strange because I've pointed the `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` variable to the Java 11 JDK.

Comment: Kind pf tricky thing to debug remotely but 1) show us your JAVA_HOME variable. 2) Check if it is not overriden in IntelliJ config file https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html 3) as a last resort, try changing it via config file

Comment: @Lesiak Changing the JDK in the .jdk file helped! Thanks!

Comment: Download IntelliJ _with_ a JDK. This should work out of the box

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen not if was changed per https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879 and the custom runtime location became invalid, see my answer for more details.

Comment: @CrazyCoder True.  Kudos to the team for making a "brings own jvm" distribution - it makes things much easier!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This issue occurs if you override the default JetBrains Runtime with some other version, IDE saves the location of this runtime under [CONFIG](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519)`\idea64.exe.jdk` file and then this runtime becomes invalid (removed or corrupted) or incompatible with the new IDE version.

The solution is to delete `idea64.exe.jdk`/`idea.exe.jdk` file so that IDE is using the default bundled JetBrains Runtime (the file name could be different depending on the product you are using, so the general guide is to delete `*.jdk` files in the IDE [config directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.1/tuning-the-ide.html#config-directory)).

Here is the file that should be deleted for most of the users on Windows:

```
c:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.1\idea64.exe.jdk
```

The issue occurs when this file points to Java 8 as IntelliJ IDEA no longer runs on Java 8 and is expecting Java 11 instead. Java 11 is already bundled, but this file overrides it, hence the problem.

Please also check [this document](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879) for the other possible ways to override IDE runtime and make sure none of these is in effect:

`IDEA_JDK_64` environment variable may also override the default runtime, you need to unset it.

Another possible issue is that the bundled runtime in `jbr` subdirectory becomes corrupted. Verify it by running `java -version` inside `IDE_HOME\jbr\bin`. Reinstalling IDE should help.

See also a [related discussion in IntelliJ IDEA forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007950019-Cannot-launch-IntelliJ-2020-1).

The issue is [being investigated in YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-237332).

Comment: Would it be feasible that Intellij verifies the integrity of the bundled JVM files?  Or is this not something that happens?

Comment: It's a new issue and we are still investigating why it happens. Yes, ideally IDE should verify the integrity of the JVM, but it may be problematic via the platform specific launchers.

Comment: Are you sure the file is not "idea.exe.jdk" (or "idea64.exe.jdk")...?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your IntelliJ version supports running on Java 11 (not just compiling with it). Additionally, if you're using Windows and just defined the JAVA_HOME variable, reboot.

Comment: I'm using the latest IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate version which should support Java 11. A reboot didn't fix the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

from 2020.1 onwards the configuration folder is located in [`%APPDATA%/Roaming/JetBrains/<product><version>`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.1/tuning-the-ide.html#config-directory) folder.

I had to delete my *.jdk file in that folder for it to reconfigure itself.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but what new information does it add to the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

- Check if it is not overriden in IntelliJ config file: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html
- as a last resort, try changing it via config file

Answer (score 0):

Just change system variable JAVA_HOME from:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre
```

to:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk
```

Works for me like charm (on Windows).