# Cannot open android-studio

Tags: java, android-studio, configuration

I installed android-studio few days back along with openjdk. And it did work fine until yesterday. But now I cannot open it. The desktop icon is dead and when i run `./studio.sh` it shows `JDK Required: Cannot load a JDK class: com.sun.jdi.Field.Please ensure you run the IDE on JDK rather than JRE`.But openjdk is still there. I am runnning on fedora32. android-studio is in `opt/` and openjdk in `var/lib/`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61145290/intellij-idea-doesnt-start-cannot-load-a-jdk-class-com-sun-jdi-field

Answer (score 0):

I suggest re-installing it, if it worked fine till some time and stopped abruptly, this would be my option.